# How to enable the FormulaEvalInApex and ApexZipSupport Feature in the Created Scratch Org

Tags: apex, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, feature-management

We thought of checking the functionality of [FormulaEvalInApex](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_formulaeval.htm&release=248&type=5) and [ApexZipSupport](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_compression.htm&release=248&type=5) which are mentioned in the IdeaExchange Spring 24 Release. These features are noted as Developer Preview. So we created a scratch org with the definition file.

```
    {
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

In the release notes it is mentioned that we should enable the FormulaEvalInApex and ApexZipSupport features to use the functionality.

Where should I enable them?

In the scratch org settings, we tried creating a scratch org with preview release. But we are not able to create them because the preview period is completed. In this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_version_selection.htm), it is mentioned that the preview period for Spring 24 will commence from Jan 7th 2024.

So Can I use these functionalities only in the preview scratch org created in the preview period?

If yes, Should I enable them in the features of the config file like this?

```
{
      "orgName": "Demo company",
      "edition": "Developer",
      "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi","FormulaEvalInApex","ApexZipSupport"],
      "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
          "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
          "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are jumping the gun. Salesforce has not enabled the preview of Spring '24 yet. You need to wait until it is available (during January 2024, take a look [here](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/admin-spring-24-release-dates-countdown)) and then use the [preview version selection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_version_selection.htm) in your `sfdx-project.json`.

Every release has a preview window during which the preview version selection works and outside of which it does not.

Once you have a preview, it is normal that you must then ensure your Apex class has the required API version set in order to access new or updated programmatic API features such as the new formula evaluation functionality.

Comment: HI @Phil W , We have few doubts regarding the JSON file accessing in our Managed Package. Could you please us. I have posted this as another question. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415121/does-using-the-atob-and-btoa-javascript-functions-impact-salesforce-security-rev

Comment: Hi @Phil W, As we are in the preview window time period we can test the preview functionalities but, I am able to create a scratch org with FormulaEvalInApex enabled in features but if I mention the ApexZipSupport feature, the scratch org is not getting created due to an Error (1): ApexZipSupport is not a valid Features value. Could please help me.

Comment: Apex API changes are **NOT** features. You don't enable them in the scratch def. You simply need to ensure you create or update your apex class that is to use the API with the required `apiVersion` in the class's related `-meta.xml` file to gain access to these new or updated APIs.

Comment: Thanks @Phil W, we created an class with version 60, still we are unable to use the functionality. I have changed my question. Could you please check it.

Comment: @S1th please do NOT retrospectively change an already answered question. You need to create a new question for this (and remove the update, please).

Comment: ,I apologize, I have created new question and removed the updates. Could you please check the new question? (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415452/unable-to-use-the-apexzipsupport-feature-using-scratch-org)