# Unable to use the ApexZipSupport feature using scratch org

Tags: apex, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, feature-management

Since we are in the preview window time period, we are able to create and check the FormulaEvalInApex functionality by creating a preview scratch org with only FormulaEvalInApex feature enabled. But we are unable to create a preview scratch org with ApexZipSupport feature enabled.

Our Config file looks like:

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi","ApexZipSupport"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

Even we tried to create a apex class with verison 60, but we couldn't save. How can we check the ApexZipSupport functionality?

```
public static void zipFunc(){
    ZipWriter writer = new ZipWriter();
    List<id> contentDocumentIds = new List<id>();
    System.debug(writer);
}
```

Comment: Please could you [edit] the question to include the class's metadata as well? I understand you've tried to create it with version 60, but it would be good to confirm this is the case. The best way to do that is to first create the class, with the function empty, and save it, then check the metadata (either through the apex classes list in the Setup UI, checking the class's version settings in the Setup UI, or by looking at the `cls-meta.xml` file when retrieving the class using the `sf` CLI).